# When calling wp_title(), do you have to create some kind of "title.php" file?

Tags: templates, hooks, title, formatting, design

... or does `wp_title()` already handle the various contexts in your blog?

This could clarify for me how I can achieve a reusable `index.php` file without having all the conditional statements inside it to handle the different title formats in the given context (page, single, posts, search, archive, date, etc...)

Also,

Could a specific post or page have a special custom formatting without breaking the rest of the use-cases? (*If this needs to be in a separate question, please let me know - it's closely tied to this question so I figured I'd merge it in here for now*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`wp_title()` template tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title) does *some* context-based output. From the Codex:

> The title text depends on the query:
>
> Single post or a Page
>
> - the title of the post (or Page)
>
> Date-based archive
>
> - the date (e.g., "2006", "2006 - January")
>
> Category
>
> - the name of the category
>
> Author page
>
> - the public name of the user

If you need to add more-specific contextual output, you can use the `wp_title` *filter hook* to modify the output.

For example, if you want to prepend the output with the Site Name:

```
<?php
function mytheme_filter_wp_title( $title ) {
    // Get the Site Name
    $site_name = get_bloginfo( 'name' );
    // Prepend it to the default output
    $filtered_title = $site_name . $title;
    // Return the modified title
    return $filtered_title;
}
// Hook into 'wp_title'
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'mytheme_filter_wp_title' );
?>
```

Taking an example from the Codex page, say you want to append the *site description* to the title output when on the site front page:

```
<?php
function mytheme_filter_wp_title( $title ) {
    // Get the Site Name
    $site_name = get_bloginfo( 'name' );
    // Prepend name
    $filtered_title = $site_name . $title;
    // If site front page, append description
    if ( is_front_page() ) {
        // Get the Site Description
        $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description' );
        // Append Site Description to title
        $filtered_title .= $site_description;
    }
    // Return the modified title
    return $filtered_title;
}
// Hook into 'wp_title'
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'mytheme_filter_wp_title' );
?>
```

Modify accordingly, to suit your needs.

In case it isn't obvious, these filter callbacks belong in `functions.php`.

**EDIT**

Missed this:

> Could a specific post or page have a special custom formatting without breaking the rest of the use-cases?

It is entirely possible. In fact, that's how most SEO Plugins work.

Here's the thing about using the `wp_title` filter to control `wp_title()` output: **you've built in the ability to play nicely with SEO Plugins and anything else that attempts to modify `wp_title()` content**, with no additional code changes required.

Comment: Thanks Chip! I was just about to ask before I read the whole thing whether or not the filter-hooks goes into `functions.php` - You sir provide the greatest answers I've seen so far! :)

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Comment: Does adding filters override the wp_title() functionality? Or does it add to existing filters of it?

Comment: "*Does adding filters override the wp_title() functionality? Or does it add to existing filters of it?*" - it depends on what you `return`. You can completely override it, or just append content.

Comment: Missed the second part of your question; it's now been added as an edit to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong, but I do not think that there is a "clean" way of doing titles without using conditionals. As far as the per-page title goes, you could create a custom meta field and check for the presence of it when you output your title.